# How to do curvefitting using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am quite new to Python. I wanted to do a sum of exponentials fit to my data using curve_fit. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata= np.array('1, 8, 8, 21, 31, 42, 63, 64, 81, 110, 156, 211, 301, 336, 735')
ydata = np.array('0.018, 0.0164, 0.0042, 0.0072, 0.0108, 0.0044, 0.0035, 0.0036, 0.0042, 0.0051, 0.0019, 0.0042, 0.0019, 8e-4, 2e-4')

def func(x,a,b,m,n):
    return a*np.exp(m*x)+b*np.exp(n*x)

curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

I get the typeerror stating: "ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Can somebody please help me with this? Also, I would like to set a constraint such that parameters a and b add to 1.

Thank you.

Comment: yeah switch the ticks out for square brackets in your array declaration.

Comment: Thank you, kpie. That works. Do you know how I can set constraints?

Comment: bounds : 2-tuple of array_like, optional & method : {‘lm’, ‘trf’, ‘dogbox’}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata= np.array([1, 8, 8, 21, 31, 42, 63, 64, 81, 110, 156, 211, 301, 336, 735])
ydata = np.array([0.018, 0.0164, 0.0042, 0.0072, 0.0108, 0.0044, 0.0035, 0.0036, 0.0042, 0.0051, 0.0019, 0.0042, 0.0019, 8e-4, 2e-4])

def func(x,a,b,m,n):
    return a*np.exp(m*x)+b*np.exp(n*x)

curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

unfortunatly `Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated`